# Does it matter what beasts I offer on the blood altar

Tags: path-of-exile

Some recipes require a couple different rare monsters, does it make a difference if I offer a monster that is under a spirits grip: for example the monster on the below picture, will this give me a better item than a monster of the same level without the warriors grip?

[image: Picture of a monster with warlord's grip and extra life]

Does crafting multiple monsters with a specific mod give a specific result? For example: all offered monsters have "Extra life", does this result in a specific mod in the crafted item or is it completely random?

Comment: I read something about using 2 corrupted blood nemesis monsters having an effect similar to using a vaal orb. So nemesis mods could have some extra effects, but no clue about possessed monsters.

Comment: The leftmost beast used in the crafting recipe will determine the item level based on its monster level, so that has an effect. I'm unsure about anything further though.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill if you have proof of that corrupted blood claim, that would be an answer I would upvote, I'm looking for all possible effects if there are any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it make a difference if I offer a monster that is under a spirits grip?

The captured beast will retain the "…'s Grip" modifier while stored in your menagerie, making it significantly more difficult to kill. *This is a nerf.*

There is no known benefit to using monsters with modifiers that are not explicitly required for the recipe.

> Does crafting multiple monsters with a specific mod give a specific result?

No such effect is currently known.

Comment: That's too bad, it would have added a slightly crazy amount of depth to the system. But it would have been awesome.

Comment: @Arperum Add that to the pile of other complaints about the design of Bestiary League, I guess. :/

Comment: I really like the bestiary system though. I do not have a personal pile of "shitty things about the league"